# Spark Auto scaling and Dynamic resource allocation

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

I went through [Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#dynamic-resource-allocation) and [Databricks](https://community.databricks.com/t5/warehousing-analytics/dynamic-allocation-vs-cluster-auto-scaling/td-p/20813#:%7E:text=Dynamic%20allocation%20is%20a%20Spark,not%20need%20external%20shuffle%20service) documentation, but could not follow the exact difference or when to use either one of Spark Auto scaling vs Dynamic resource allocation.

What is the difference between Auto scaling and Dynamic resource allocation in Spark. Are both work on scaling up and down of executors based on load? or Auto scaling scales worker nodes and Dynamic allocation scales executors?